# Return first value from multiple columns that passes checks

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have some an array of columns of multiple statements of the same data, some meeting criteria I have set, some not.

I wish to return the first (lefthand-most) value that fits my criteria. See below example of the data I have, with three separate values for "Lat".

```
Index   Lat_1   Lat_2   Lat_3
1       52.3    80      69
2       80      52.3    69
3       69      80      52.3
4       69      55.0    52.3
```

For this example, it can be considered that the criteria is being greater than or equal to 50 and less than or equal to 60. This means what I want is as below:

```
Index   Lat_1   Lat_2   Lat_3   Correct_lat
1       52.3    80.0    69.0    52.3
2       80.0    52.3    69.0    52.3
3       69.0    80.0    52.3    52.3
4       69.0    55.0    52.3    55.0
```

Is there a way to achieve this without using a number of nested if statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your original table is in A1:D5 (with headers in row 1), in E2 put **array formula***:

`=INDEX(B2:D2,MATCH(TRUE,ABS(B2:D2-55)<=5,0))`

Copy down as required.

**Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, you first hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, and only then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets `{ }` around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*